# How the default auto-generated login page is created (spring security 5 oauth2)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am following the new support of spring security 5.x for oauth2.
Trying the [samples: oauth2-login](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.2.1.RELEASE/samples/boot/oauth2login),I am unable to understand how the default auto-generated login page is created ( what is the handler for '/login' endpoint) ?

Any idea please ?

Comment: I was looking for [OAuth2LoginConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer.html).

Comment: "if `loginPage(String)` is not configured and `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` is available, than a default login page will be made available"